# How to import JSON file into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I’ve been striking out on several different approaches to loading this data into Pandas. If anyone has any suggestions for these exceptions it would be much appreciated! The file name changes in some examples between tweet_json.txt and tweet_json.json as I was trying different methods.

```
with open('tweet_json.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

results in : `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 3974)`

```
df_3 = pd.read_json('tweet_json.json', lines = True)
```

results in : `ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding object value`

```
with open('tweet_json.txt') as file:
    status = []
    for line in file:
        data = json.loads(line)
df_3 = pd.Dataframe(data)
```

results in: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 1626 (char 1625)`

The only time I had remotely any success was using json.dumps() but this just loaded it into a single column dataframe with nothing parsed, and being that the json looks like a multi level dictionary I would have no idea how to go about separating it:

```
data = []
with open('tweet_json.json') as f:    
    for line in f:         
         data.append(json.dumps(line))
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] by providing a few lines of the JSON data file (shortened and anonymized, if needed) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Looks like your .json file does not actually contain JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the way I solved it. I was missing defining which columns specifically to import and using map. I still don't know how to just import the entire JSON to a df but this does what I needed.

```
tweets_data = []
tweet_file = open('tweet_json.txt', "r")
for line in tweet_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue   
tweet_file.close()
tweet_info = pd.DataFrame()
tweet_info['id'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['id'], tweets_data))
tweet_info['retweet_count'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['retweet_count'], tweets_data))
tweet_info['favorite_count'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['favorite_count'], tweets_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) or [read_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html) to read a json file into a dataframe.

If you have nested json structures you can also use [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) function